# How I calculate the distance between to coordinates with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, geolocation, coordinates, distance, maxmind

I am currently working on the Maxmind database. However, it contains hundreds of thousands of duplicate entries. For example:

Newcastle Upon Tyne:

```
369137  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE20    54.9881 -1.6194
369332  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE6 54.9881 -1.6194
369345  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE13    54.9881 -1.6194
369355  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE3 54.9881 -1.6194
369356  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE5 54.9881 -1.6194
369645  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE4 54.9881 -1.6194
369706  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE15    54.9881 -1.6194
369959  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE12    54.9881 -1.6194
370114  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE27    54.9881 -1.6194
```

Newcastle (I removed some of them because there's too many to paste here):

```
382 ZA  2   Newcastle       -27.758 29.9318
2279    US  OK  Newcastle   73065   35.2323 -97.6008
26459   US  CA  Newcastle   95658   38.873  -121.1543
22382   CA  ON  Newcastle   l1b1j9  43.9167 -78.5833
38995   AU  2   Newcastle       -32.9278    151.7845
40025   US  ME  Newcastle   4553    44.0438 -69.5675
47937   GB  I7  Newcastle       54.9881 -1.6194
119830  US  ME  Newcastle   4553    44.0438 -69.5675
119982  US  NE  Newcastle   68757   42.6475 -96.9232
115052  US  CA  Newcastle   95658   38.873  -121.1543
120603  US  NE  Newcastle   68757   42.6475 -96.9232
127931  US  OK  Newcastle   73065   35.2323 -97.6008
136726  CA  ON  Newcastle       43.9167 -78.5833
136915  US  TX  Newcastle   76372   33.245  -98.9103
137128  US  WY  Newcastle   82701   43.8396 -104.5681
137130  US  WY  Newcastle   82701   43.8396 -104.5681
```

Given that there are more than one Newcastle cities in the world and also that it returns all the different postcodes for Newcastle even if it contains the same lat/lon, how can we remove the duplicate entries?

I have taken a look at this [Eliminate duplicate cities from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816945/eliminate-duplicate-cities-from-database) which comes up with this potential solution:

```
delete from climate.maxmind_city mc where id in (
select
  max(c1.id)
from
  climate.maxmind_city c1,
  climate.maxmind_city c2
where
  c1.id <> c2.id and
  c1.country = c2.country and
  c1.name = c2.name and
  earth_distance(
    ll_to_earth( c1.latitude_decimal, c1.longitude_decimal ),
    ll_to_earth( c2.latitude_decimal, c2.longitude_decimal ) ) <= 35
group by
  c1.country, c1.name
order by
  c1.country, c1.name
)
```

However, earth_distance is a postgresql function and we are using MySQL. How can I therefore replace the earth_distance function with a similar MySQL approach?

Comment: If the only thing you are asking for is calculating distance between 2 points in MySQL then try this: http://www.tech-problems.com/calculating-distance-in-mysql-using-spatial-point-type/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how can I incorporate SQRT(POW(69.1 * (fld_lat - ( $lat )), 2) + POW(69.1 * (($lon) - fld_lon) * COS(fld_lat / 57.3 ), 2 )) AS distance into my query? I don't want to be creating new tables.

Comment: You can create a your own function/procedure in MySQL.

Comment: If you only want cities and their coordinates the `Maxmind`database is not suitable as it is for ip addresses and there coordinates. If you remove the duplicates it is of no use for ip's.